# Sony Audio Control API - Can't Change Input on AV Receiver

Tags: sony-audio-control-api

I've been playing around with Sony's [Audio Control API](https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api) recently, with the aim of setting up 'scenes' at home, where I can switch devices on/off, set lighting, etc with one command.

I can list available inputs with [getCurrentExternalTerminalsStatus](https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/hardware-overview/api-references/svs/getcurrentexternalterminalsstatus), but can't actually change inputs via [setActiveTerminal](https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/hardware-overview/api-references/svs/setactiveterminal).

**Request**

```
{
    "method": "setActiveTerminal",
    "id": 13,
    "params": [
    {
        "active": "active",
        "uri": "extInput:sat-catv"
    }],
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "error": [
        15,
        "unsupported operation"
    ],
    "id": 13
}
```

Judging by the response given, I'm guessing that my AV receiver (STR-DN860) doesn't support this for some reason, but I'm posting this here since Sony's [support pages](https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/get-support) suggest to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use "setPlayContent" and not "setActiveTerminal".

"setActiveTerminal" powers "off" or "on" the output zone.

To change the output to "sat-catv" try

```
{
  "method":"setPlayContent",
  "id":47,
  "params":[
  {
    "output":"extOutput:zone?zone=1",
    "uri":"extInput:sat-catv"
  }],
  "version":"1.2"
}
```

using curl

```
curl -i -d '{"method":"setPlayContent","id":47,"params":[{"output":"extOutput:zone?zone=1","uri":"extInput:sat-catv"}],"version":"1.2"}' http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000
```

"setActiveTerminal" can be used to power on/off the device similar to "setPowerStatus" with:

```
curl -i -d '{"method":"setActiveTerminal","id":13,"params":[{"active":"inactive","uri":"extOutput:zone?zone=1"}],"version":"1.0"}' http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000/sony/avContent
```

But can also power on/off each zone individually by using ?zone=2, ?zone=3... dependent on how many zones your device support.

Don't have a STR-DN860 to test on but I think this should work.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! Knew it'd be something simple... Thanks!