# Sony Soundbar HT-ZF9 API setActiveTerminal showing Error 12 ; other APi's are working

Tags: api, sony

I want to control the soundbar by LAN.

I can turn on and off the soundbar with postman and the given Sony Api's.

When i Want to change the input, in Postman appears error 12.
I don't understand why, because other API's like `getInformation` are working fine. (network, url, port, connection, and library should be also ok)

From the Api `getInformation`, I could read the information with the name of the inputs.

But then I paste them to `setActiveTerminal`, *Error 12* occurs.

Does anyone know, where is the problem??

Here, the used code:

http://169.254.75.11:10000/sony/avContent

```
{
 "method":"setActiveTerminal",
 "id":55,
 "params":[
  {
   "active": "active",
    "uri": "extInput:hdmi?port=1"
  }
 ],
 "version":"1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setActiveTerminal` is for activating or deactivating output ports `extOutput` or "zone" that it is called on the STR-DN1080. Since the ZF9 don't have multi zone capabilities the use of this method is very limited.

I'm guessing you want to set the input port and that is done via `setPlayContent` (with out the `output` parameter in the json for ZF9) see
[Sony Audio Control API - Can't Change Input on AV Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776553/sony-audio-control-api-cant-change-input-on-av-receiver/51782353#51782353) for more info.